# loading bitmap from application folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using  the below code to load a .png file to bitmap

```
Bitmap original;
                    if (tbp.LanguageTypingdir =="LTR")
                    {

                        original = new Bitmap(@"Images\CC_Logo.png");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        original = new Bitmap(@"Images\CC_Logo_ar.png");
                    }
```

i get error `Additional information: Parameter is not valid.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about yours, but I know the following syntax works for loading a bitmap image:

```
Image img = Bitmap.FromFile("C:/Users/xxx/Pictures/1.jpg");
```

If you need to work on the Bitmap class, just cast the Image object.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = img as Bitmap;
```